# c++ weird segmentation fault

Tags: c++, class, segmentation-fault

```
int Celda :: look(int dni)
{
    bool found = false; 
    int i = 0; int pos = -1;
    //tam_ sometimes have a strange value, but I only
    while(i < tam_ && !found){ 
        //touch tam_ in the constructor, is the size of Celda
        if(dni == bloques_[i]){    
           found = true;
            pos = i;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    return pos;
}
```

In main I call a method of another class that calls other  that uses the look method I've copied here. In some cases it works, but other times the program stops giving a segmentation fault.

When I use a debugger, I've created another variable for store the tam_ value (tam_ is int type), and when I reach that line or the while loop (with condition with tam_) sometimes the segmentation fault appears.

The constructor of Celda is:

```
Celda :: Celda(int tamanio)
{
bloques_ = new int[tamanio];
bloq_ocupados_ = 0;
tam_ = tamanio;
for(int i = 0 ; i < tam_ ; ++i){
    bloques_[i] = 0;
}
```

}

```
Tabla :: Tabla(int numcel, int tambloq)
{
    nceldas_ = numcel; 
    tam_bloque_ = tambloq;
    tabla_ = new Celda*[nceldas_];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nceldas_ ; ++i){
        tabla_[i] = new Celda(tam_bloque_);
    }
    ocupadas_ = 0;
}

class Celda
{
    private:
        int* bloques_;
        int bloq_ocupados_;
        int tam_;
```

And down the public section

```
int Tabla :: busq_lineal(int dni) //si pos_dentro acaba valiendo -1, no se encontró
{
    bool encontrado = false; 
    int pos = hash(dni), comparaciones = 0, pos_dentro, pos_fuera;
    int tamaniotab = nceldas_ * tabla_[0]->gettam();
    while(!encontrado && comparaciones < tamaniotab){
        pos_dentro = tabla_[pos]->buscar(dni);
        if(pos_dentro != -1){ //si lo encuentro...
            encontrado = true;
            pos_fuera = pos;
            comparaciones += pos_dentro + 1;
        }else if(pos < nceldas_ - 1){ //mientras no nos salgamos de la tabla, avanzamos
            ++pos;
            comparaciones += tabla_[0]->gettam();
        }else {
            pos = 0; //si nos salimos, volvemos al principio
            comparaciones += tabla_[0]->gettam();
        }
    }
    return comparaciones;
}
```

Comment: It is considered a good practice to use English identifiers. Just an offtopic note. And more ontopic: could we have a testcase? http://sscce.org/

Comment: Can you post destructor, copy constructor and assignment operator for class `Celda`?

Comment: For a segfault to happen in the condition, you'd have to have a bad `this` pointer. Could you check if `this` makes sense at the point of crash?

Comment: Show your complete class

Comment: @Arkadiy you are right, the debbuger told me somtething about this pointer...what is the solution for that??

Comment: What is the exact asm instruction that the segfault occurs on and what is the value of the register causing the fault?  Many clues to be had there.

Comment: Can you post the line of code where instance of class `Celda` is created? Also the `private:` section of `Celda` definition would be helpful.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that code. The problem is surely when you use your class. Can you post a code snippet that uses the `Tabla` class?

Comment: `tabla_ = new Celda*[nceldas_];` astrisk after `Celda` makes no sense for me in this case. Were you misstyping or this is actually fragement of your code? Apparentely you want to declare array of `Celdas` not an array of pointers to `Celda`. Am I wrong?

Comment: is a real code, because tabla_ is Celda** type

Comment: The program is a hash table (don't know how to say in english) and hash in this case is only the % of pos with 199 (the nearest prime number to 200)

Comment: And where is `Tabla` constructor called?

Comment: Do you have at least 200 entries in the table?

Comment: !!!! fontaini you are the winner, I made the table with 100 elements, 0 to 99. Now I've used the next prime to 100 (97) and works perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is most probably in this line:

```
int pos = hash(dni);
```

As you said, your `hash` function just returns `dni % 199`. This will work okay, only if you have at least 200 items in your hash table.

Answer (score -2):

Shouldnt it be "i++"?

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < tam_ ; i++){
    bloques_[i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: i++ is slower than ++i, I do all my for loops with ++i for a little improve in performance

Comment: Prefix vs postfix is **not** the culprit here.

Comment: prefix (++i) and postfix (i++) increment operators both increment the value. prefix is more efficient and is often preferred.

Comment: OK, my bad, thought it would increment before the iteration (that way looping from 1 to size instead 0 to size-1).

Comment: And the compiler creators know it, just like * and / vs << and >>.  Let's not go here again.

Comment: ++i and i++ produce the same same in for loop increments. Modern compilers produce the same code for both ++i & i++ used in for loops. So performance-gain argument is a little obsolete. Note that using in stateents, for example x=i++; is entirely different.